# How did Wolverine pass through the spinning blades unharmed?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-2000

In the first X-Men film (2000) near the end when Wolverine gets lifted up by Storm (and Jean to stabilize him) and he catches the "helm" of the device containing Rogue who was surrounded by spinning blades, he casually jumps down to try and free her.

Why didn't he get violently mutilated by the blades? Did I miss something obvious or was it production error?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### The blades aren't circular.

Yes, you missed that the "blades" of the mutation generator are **horseshoe shaped.**

### How did he get down?

From above there's no obstruction to simply jumping down.

[image]